# What does this sql query do on execution?

Tags: mysql

`username` and `password` are fields in the table `Employeeid`:

```
select * from Employeeid where username=? and password=?
```

Comment: Hmm, this is more a question for a Google search than for asking on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It retrieves all fields for a specific user whose username and password matches the two parameters included in the actual call.

Answer (score 0):

The question marks are placeholders.  This query doesn't do anything by itself until you send the corresponding parameters.

After that, this query selects all rows from the EmployeeId table where the username and password match the given parameters.